# How can I have different ip for differnt distrubutions on wsl2?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running 5 different `Ubuntu` distro on wsl2 but all are having the same ip address.For example `Ubuntu 18.04` and `Ubuntu 20.04` are having the same ip. Is it possible to have different ips on each `Ubuntu` versions?

Comment: Any progress on this front?

Comment: Unfortunately not, ended up doing my research on two machines :-(

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yeah, I’m pretty sure that it’s not possible. ... something about all the instances using the same VM behind the scenes. I wound up disabling Hyper-V and Virtual Machine Platform (Windows Features), and switching to using multiple VirtualBox VMs. I set all their Network settings to “Bridge Adapter,” which successfully made them all have their own IP registered with the router. ... the IPs may or may not persist across reboot. We’ll see.

Comment: An interesting approach, though I had limited time and couldn't look into this further.
Also thank you for posting the detail, It would be helpful for the people looking for the solution.

Comment: @LeifSegen Please can you give a detailed explanation on how you resolved this problem? 

I would love to have multiple WSL distro running on their respective unique IP address.

And did the IPs persist across reboot?

Comment: @Ikechukwu Sure, let me know how it goes. Admittedly, I didn't boot it all up again because I'm using Docker at the moment, which is mutually exclusive with running VirtualBox.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I do appreciate your response.

Comment: @LeifSegen This isn't exactly what I wanted initially, but this is what I've been able to come up with https://superuser.com/a/1685919/1065065

Answer (score 1):

You can create new processes with new network namespaces, so you can achieve network isolation.

```
ip netns add net1
ip netns exec net1 ip addr add 192.168.99.10/24 dev sit0
ip netns exec net1 exec bash
```

Reference: https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2016/04/10/network-namespaces/

Answer (score 1):

May you can try this solution: https://superuser.com/a/1715457/860784, with which I managed to get multiple IPs. And I can ping each other.

However, after reboot these IPs lost, and  I still get my distros the same IP, which is exact the windows ip.

May you can sovle your problem and my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Full disclosure: This answer does not address networking between to wsl2 instances. Rather, it presents - as requested from a commenter - an alternative way to have two guest operating systems to each have their own IP address within a network that is "inside" the host OS.*

The following allows for two VMs (rather than wsl2 instances) to have different IP addresses within a network within a host Windows 10 operating system:

- Prerequisites in no particular order:

  - Disable the Hyper-V Windows Feature. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/virtualization-apps-not-work-with-hyper-v#disable-hyper-v-in-control-panel) describes a variety of ways to go about it, but I went the Control Panel route.
  - Install VirtualBox
- Set up a network for the VMs to share:

  1. Open VirtualBox
  2. Click File > Preferences
  3. Click Network
  4. Click the icon with a plus sign (`+`) in it to add a new network
- Create your VMs and connect them to this network

  1. Create the VM and give it an operating system as you would otherwise
  2. Shut down the VM
  3. Select the VM in the main VirtualBox window, click the Settings/gear button
  4. Click Network
  5. Select NAT Network for "Attached to"
  6. Select the name of the network you created above. (A sample that worked for me is below.)
     [image]
- Customize the overall network settings for the VMs

  1. Return to main VirtualBox window > File > Preferences > Network
  2. Click gear icon to edit the network
  3. Click **Port Forwarding**
  4. Enter details (such as the following, but modified for you needs) to direct traffic from local host to certain IP addresses/ports within this network
     [image]

Comment: The question is about WSL2, why would you post an answer that has nothing to do with WSL2...